# Exclude specific subdirectory from SVN Checkout in subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

The problem is pretty straightforward, I'm just not very well-versed in these tools (or CVSes in general).

Each branch of the project contains 4 folders:

```
branch-1
    folder1
    ...
    folder4
branch-2
    folder1
    ...
    folder4
...
```

`folder4` is ginormous (~2GB), contains things I'm usually not interested in, and I'd rather not download it every single time -- it takes forever, and takes up space.

I see that the "Checkout from SVN" dialog has a Depth field, with options:

1. Fully recursive
2. Immediate children, including folders
3. Only file children
4. Only this item

None of these options is quite what I want. 1 and 2 will still download `folder4`, while 3 and 4 will omit everything.

Ideally, I'd be able to simply omit `folder4` from the download initially, with the option to pull it down later. I don't mind seeing it as an incoming change (and simply ignoring it) during sync operations.

Any ideas? Am I missing something?

P.S. I tried to post this question in Super User, but the site is giving me real problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using Subclipse:

1. Check out using the "Immediate children" option. `folder1`, etc. will be empty.
2. Select the empty folders (except `folder4`) in the newly-checked out project.
3. Choose Team → Update to Version...
4. Set the depth to "Fully recursive".
5. Tick "Change working copy to specified depth".
6. Click OK.

Another way to do this involves the `svn` command line client:

1. Check out using the "Only this item" option. The top-level directory will be empty (`folder1` etc. will be missing).
2. `cd project-dir`
3. `svn up folder1 folder2 folder3`

Comment: Close! I don't have the option `Team > Update to Version...`, but I do have a `Team > Switch to another Branch/Tag/Revision...`. The rest is accurate. Thanks!